# blade template laravel get stuck with wamp server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, wamp, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel. I watched some tutorials on youtube and try something did a blade template but it couldn't load, it gave me a message

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

my code

**Route.php**

```
<?php




Route::get('list', 'HsController@getList');
```

**HsController.php**

```
<?php

class HsController extends BaseController {



    public function getList()
    {
        return View::make('List');
    }

}
```

in views folder i have a folder named Layout include some files such as: main.blade.php, foot.blade.php, menu.blade.php

**main.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
    @include('layout.menu');
    @yield('content');
    @include('layout.foot');
</body>
</html>
```

**foot.blade.php**

```
<div>
    Footer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
</div>
```

**menu.blade.php**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and important thing is **list.blade.php** :

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

please correct my code 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error is in `list.blade.php` file

You have:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
```

it should be:

```
@extends('layout.main')
```

because the folder name is `Layout`. Another possible problem is the name of `Layout` directory. You should change it into lowercase `layout` - because on Linux webserver it won't probably work.